# Finding specific values in nested json using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a file containing a large number of nested json objects.  I pasted a snippet of it below. I am trying to use python to query all of the objects in the file to pull out those objects that have at least one custom feeds - url value that begins with "http://commshare"  Some objects will not have any custom feeds, and the others will have one or more custom feed each of which might or might not begin with that string I am searching for.  Any help would be appreciated!  I am very new to Python.

**Example JSON**:

```
 [{
    "empid": "12345",
    "values": {
      "custom_feeds": {
        "custom_feeds": [
          {
            "name": "Bulletins",
            "url": "http://infoXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
          }
        ]
      },
      "gadgetTitle": "InfoSec Updates",
      "newWindow": false,
      "article_limit_value": 10,
      "show_source": true
    }
  },
  {
    "empid": "23456",
    "values": {
      "custom_feeds": {
        "custom_feeds": [
          {
            "name": "1 News",
            "url": "http://blogs.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "name": "2 News",
            "url": "http://info.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "name": "3 News",
            "url": "http://blogs.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          },
          {
            "name": "4 News",
            "url": "http://commshare.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
          }
        ]
      },
      "gadgetTitle": "Org News",
      "newWindow": false,
      "article_limit_value": 10,
      "show_source": true
    }
  },  {
    "empid": "34567",
    "values": {
      "custom_feeds": {
        "custom_feeds": []
      },
      "gadgetTitle": "Org News",
      "newWindow": false,
      "article_limit_value": 10,
      "show_source": true
    }
  }]
```

Comment: Load it into a python dict using `json.load(open('path/to/input/file'))`. Iterate through each object (dictionary) and check `len(obj['values']['custom_feeds']['custom_feeds'])`

Comment: I don't believe that's valid JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file is named `input.json` and you want the object for each feed, you could parse the JSON and create a new list where the feeds meet your criteria using list comprehension:

```
import json

with open('input.json') as input_file:
    items = json.loads(input_file.read())

feeds = [{'name': feed['name'], 'url': feed['url'], 'empid': item['empid']}
    for item in items
    for feed in item['values']['custom_feeds']['custom_feeds']
    if feed['url'].startswith('http://commshare')]

assert feeds == [{'name': '4 News', 'url': 'http://commshare.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'empid': '23456'}]
```

Comment: This is great - thanks!  How can I add the corresponding empid on so I know the empid attached to each url?

Comment: One way would be to construct a new object in the comprehension with an `empid` field (edited to show example).